# use scapy to send UDP ping with a high frequency, why only receive the first few ICMP port unreachable message?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, scapy, icmp

In a linux system, I use `scapy` to send a high frequency UDP ping. For example: each 20 milliseconds, send a UDP packet; a total of 100. But I can only get the first few ICMP port unreachable answer.

```
 pkt = IP(dst=dst)/UDP(dport=RandShort())
 ans,_ = sr(pkt*100, inter=0.02, timeout=3)
```

I tried to use `tcpdump` to capture packet and found that all UDP packets have been sent to the target machine, but only a few ICMP packet came back to the source machine. What would cause this?

If I use ICMP ping，this does not happen.

I guess:

1. may be caused by the target machine's system kernel parameter which process icmp packet
2. may be caused by the icmp packet routing switch strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate of ICMP packets is hard limited by the kernel to prevent DDOS attacks. Usually to only 1 packet per second. Almost impossible to get anything faster than that in any external (internet) router. [Example](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/is-there-any-way-to-solve-this-limiting-icmp-ping-response.1442/)

Comment: thanks!  By `man 7 icmp`, I found the kernel parameters and modified kernel parameters  to change the rate of icmp packets.